# Asp.net Core 2.0 Dependent .dlls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When you install a nuget package in an Asp.net Core 2.0 project targeting netcoreapp2.0, where are the physical .dlls put? They are not in the bin or the GAC.

Thanks

Comment: It is inside `C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages`

Comment: Are you using `dotnet publish` when you build?

Comment: See [.NET Core assembly search order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619499/net-core-assembly-search-order/46619618#46619618)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net Core and NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205092/net-core-and-nuget)